# IIS Renamed Images still show previous contents - Caching issue?

Tags: windows, caching, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012

On our website using IIS 8, we are serving done jpgs on an image management screen.The images are on a separate hard drive that is connected in IIS via a virtual folder. All the photos are named with the entity ID followed by the photo number. So:

```
Photo 1: 58935928.1.jpg
Photo 2: 58935928.2.jpg
Photo 3: 58935928.3.jpg
```

If I want to reorder photo 3 to photo slot 1, I have to rename photo 3 to 58935928.3.jpg.TEMP then rename photo 1 to 58935928.3.jpg and then 58935928.3.jpg.TEMP to 58935928.1.jpg. This works fine. However when viewing the page and refreshing it, the images returned for 58935928.1.jpg is still the old image before it was renamed. After around 5-10 minutes, a refresh will now show the correct images.

We thought this was a browsing caching issue. Ctrl-F5 force refresh did not fix it and setting no cache metadata on the page did not either. We noticed that when this occurs, and we go to different browsers, the images still display incorrectly. This lead us to thinking server side caching since a new browser instance is also getting the wrong image.

We went in iis and configured output caching to no cache on kernal and user just to see if it would fix it. No difference. We don't want to go so hard as to disable cache on everything, just jpgs would be fine.

Why is this happening? This is causing confusion for our users as they reorder the images and they are actually reordered on the file system but IIS seems to be serving the old image instead of the new one.

Comment: are these files being served by the static file handler, or is some code/module involved?

Comment: @MisterSmith I'm thinking the static file handler. I did not write anything code wise to serve it up, just a straight <img src="photo.1.jpg" />

Comment: How is iis server attached to your external disk? Is it locally or network attached?

Comment: @MisterSmith Locally as a separate drive letter.

Comment: hmm. back to iis caching then... is there anything in your applicationHost.config thats overriding your web.config?

Comment: When did you start getting this issue? Anything else change?

Comment: The issue just showed up now as we changed the way our photo system works with drag and drop reordering which could potentially affect all photos. We didn't reorder before. In the applicationhost I see serveral cache entries but nothing that looks like it's overwriting. Everything had false except for isapiFilters which had <filter name="ASP.Net_4.0_32bit" path="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />

Comment: sorry no idea. it does seem to be cache related but i dont know where. Any chance you could use a typical caching busting technique of creating new filenames (.4, .5, .6 etc) - that would almost certainly avoid this problem - but probably creates others.

Comment: Actually - appending a query string with a timestamp or other unique value might force IIS to check whats on disk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170875/discussion-between-mistersmith-and-solidsnake4444).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong when I said the folder was mounted as a virtual folder. It was actually a mounted volume. I don't see how this makes a difference either way HOWEVER once I removed it as a mounted volume and made it a virtual folder, everything worked properly.

So in my case, it was because all the photos were on a mounted volume that was causing the issue.